# Parent > Child animation unexpected - different Angular 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or I have a lack of understanding of the expected behaviour.

On the following codepen ([With Angular 1.4](http://codepen.io/motionimaging/pen/a17908257c4d9dfa1d05c3af61cee407)) I expect the parent to animate followed by the child items to animate. However, the parent does not animate and the child items still wait for the transition period.

In this codepen ([With Angular 1.3](http://codepen.io/motionimaging/pen/9250df68ed82072ca5638a1f74c2b341)) the animations work as expected.

Is this a bug, am I missing something, or has something changed in 1.3 to 1.4 that I have not followed?

Code for completion

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">
   <button ng-click="toggleItems()">Toggle Items</button>

   <div class="parent" ng-show="items">
       <p class="child" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  background:#f00;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}
.parent.ng-hide {
  opacity:0;
}

.child {
  background:#0f0;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}
.child.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;
}
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.items = null;

$scope.toggleItems = function(){

    if( $scope.items ){

      $scope.items = null;

    } else {

      $scope.items = [
        {name: 'item 1'},
        {name: 'item 2'},
        {name: 'item 3'},
     ];

    }
  };

});
```

Comment: It seems that the .ng-hide-animate class (as well as other classes) is not getting added to the parent item if there is a child with ng-repeat. I have updated both codepens to show a parent with and without ng-repeat as a child.

Comment: Added an issue about this on angular GitHub ... wait'n'see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12276 .

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the issue. But it finally seems like an Angular bug or just an outdated angular css:

**1.3.5**

Using ng-hide with ng-animate will apply :

ng-hide-animate ng-hide-add ng-hide-add-active when added.

ng-hide-animate ng-hide-remove ng-hide-remove-active when removed.

This works well since i found this line of CSS about ng-hide :

```
.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

This mean your div will not be display when there is no animation. When there is an animation it will show and produce the animation.

**1.4.0**

In the official documentation Angular added this :

> CSS Class-based Animations Class-based animations (animations that are
>   triggered via ngClass, ngShow, ngHide and some other directives) have
>   a slightly different naming convention. Class-based animations are
>   basic enough that a standard transition or keyframe can be referenced
>   on the class being added and removed.
>
> For example if we wanted to do a CSS animation for ngHide then we
>   place an animation on the .ng-hide CSS class:

```
<div ng-show="bool" class="fade">   Show and hide me </div> 
<button ng-click="bool=true">Toggle</button>

<style> .fade.ng-hide {   transition:0.5s linear all;   opacity:0; }
</style>
```

This mean that on **1.4.0** using ng-hide will simple add and remove ng-hide class.

**/!** In your codePen exemple i found that this line is still there in the CSS

```
.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Wich that each time you add ng-hide or remove it, you'll simple set "display:none" wich mean that no animation can be run. You'll need to override this behavior to use proper animations.

Doing this :

```
.parent.ng-hide {
  display:block!important;
  opacity:0;
}
```

Could do the trick but i'm not really sure that this is a safe way to do this.

At least i found the explanation, it would require more investigation to know how to deal with it in a proper way.

Hope it helped.

Comment: interestiong spot. My interpretation from this line of their docs seems to suggest that using display: block !important; shouldn't be necassary. So perhaps some outdated code found it's way back in? "Keep in mind that, as of AngularJS version 1.3.0-beta.11, there is no need to change the display property to block during animation states--ngAnimate will handle the style toggling automatically for you."

Comment: @PaulGreenChameleon I'm actually doing some further investigation, and the issue would come from the fact that the parent have no height when there is no ng-repeat element inside. ng-show animation works well if the content is static : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpegyM

Comment: I have amended the codepens to have three cases - static, ng-repeat and mixed. The mixed has a line of static code to start (and thus some height to the partent), but the parent does still not get the correct classes and thus does not animate correctly

Comment: @PaulGreenChameleon Was trying the same thing. the behavior behind this looks like my first spot : When you use it without ng-repeat inside, you have the "ng-hide-animate" CSS like in 1.3.5. Wich cause the ng-hide not to hide before the animation is over. When you add it ng-hide simply add and remove ng-hide

Comment: @PaulGreenChameleon The issue is confirmed https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12276#issuecomment-118981314 and will be corrected soon.

Comment: @PaulGreenChameleon The correction has been comit. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12276#issuecomment-118981314

Comment: that's great, I'd seen that :) Looking forward to making it into the next release and then I can update :)